# Divergence of inverse square vector field

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

After trying to get the divergence of a vector field I got:
$${\nabla \cdot \Bigg(\frac{\vec r}{|r|^3}\Bigg)=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}.\frac{1}{r^2}=-\frac{2}{r^3}}$$
But in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law_for_gravity#cite_note-Griffiths-1) found that this must be
$${\nabla \cdot \Bigg(\frac{\vec r}{|r|^3}\Bigg)=4\pi \delta(r)}$$
What is my mistake and where does my intuition get wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide the precise wikipedia link?

Comment: Typically $r$ will be a scalar quantity, so it will help Readers if you elaborate more on your calculations/definitions for the try you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the divergence in spherical coordinates, expressed in terms of derivatives, would take the form

$$\nabla \cdot \vec A = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} [r^2 A^r] + \ldots$$

where $A^r$ is the radial component of the vector field $\vec A$.  In this case, that's $1/r^2$, so we naively get 0 for this contribution.

Of course, this formula cannot be valid at the origin (there's a $1/r^2$ in it), so we resort to an alternative definition of divergence, one that is regular at the origin:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec A |_{\vec 0} = \lim_{\delta r \to 0} \frac{1}{4 \pi (\delta r)^3/3} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \vec A \cdot \hat r \, (\delta r)^2 \, \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi$$

This basically follows from the divergence theorem and is a general alternative definition for divergence that eschews derivatives.  It also can be done with curl and gradient instead.  The limit process, of course, makes this entirely equivalent to a derivative.

Evaluating this definition for $\vec A = \hat r/r^2$ at $r = \delta r$ (as we're integrating over a sphere of this radius, and then taking the limit) gives

$$\left. \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\hat r}{r^2} \right) \right|_{\vec 0} = \lim_{\delta r \to 0} \frac{3}{\delta r} $$

which obviously diverges (positively, as negative radii have no meaning).

So this is a vector field whose divergence is zero everywhere except the origin, where its divergence...well, diverges.  That all certainly sounds like a delta function.

Typically, one uses the divergence theorem directly to verify the stated condition of the delta function: that its integral over any region containing zero is 1.  That is, we do

$$4\pi \int_0^r \nabla \cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2} r^2 \, dr= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{\hat r}{r^2} \cdot \hat r r^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi$$

If $\nabla \cdot \hat r/r^2 = 4 \pi \delta$, then the surface integral on the left should evaluate to $4\pi$ (which it does, obviously).  This is not 100% formally sound, but you can always check this by integrating against a test function (a scalar field would do), just as you would in 1d.

Comment: Thank you. Only one thing I did not understand-what was wrong with my derivation,

Comment: You thought that the divergence in spherical coordinates is just a partial derivative with respect to $r$ for the radial part, and it's not. The correct form (with $r^2$ running around) is what I stated, and it can be derived using the integral form that I used throughout this answer, if you're curious how that comes to be.

Comment: OK, one more thing-why this derivative must be taken in spherical divergence but not catesian.

Comment: I assume you mean why there's an $r^2$ in the derivative when you do the divergence using spherical coordinates, but no such term when you compute divergence in cartesian. Using the integral definition of divergence, you would see that the $r^2$ comes from the surface element at constant $r$: $r^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi$.  The $\sin \theta$ drops when looking at the radial derivative, but the $r^2$ remains.  The formulas for divergence and other such derivatives are usually provided in reference material for any vector calculus textbook, so you don't have to derive them yourself.

Answer (score 4):

A common way to show that $\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\hat r}{r^2}\right)=4\pi \delta (\vec r)$ is to regularize the function $\left(\frac{\hat r}{r^2}\right)$ in terms of a parameter, say $a$.  To that end, let $\vec \psi$ be the regularized function given by

$$\vec \psi(\vec r;a)=\frac{\vec r}{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \tag 1$$

Taking the divergence of $(1)$ reveals that

$$\nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)=\frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}$$

Now, any sufficiently smooth test function $\phi$, we have that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0}\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)\phi(\vec r)dV&=\lim_{a \to 0}\int_V \frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}\phi(\vec r)dV\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

if $V$ does not include the origin.

Now, suppose that $V$ does include the origin.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0}\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)\phi(\vec r)dV&=\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{V-V_{\delta}} \frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}\phi(\vec r)dV+\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{V_{\delta}} \frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}\phi(\vec r)dV\\\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{V_{\delta}} \frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}\phi(\vec r)dV
\end{align}$$

where $V_{\delta}$ is a spherical region centered at $\vec r=0$ with radius $\delta$.  For any $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that $|\phi(\vec r)-\phi(0)|\le \epsilon/(4\pi)$ whenever $0<|\vec r|< \delta$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0}\left|\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)(\phi(\vec r)-\phi(0))\,dV\right|&\le \lim_{a\to 0} \int_{V_{\delta}} \left|\phi(\vec r)-\phi(0)\right|\frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}dV\\\\
&\le \left(\frac{\epsilon}{4\pi}\,4\pi\right)\,\lim_{a \to 0}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}r^2\,dr\\\\
&\le \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have for any test function $\phi$,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0}\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)\phi(\vec r)\,dV&=4\pi \phi(0)
\end{align}$$

and it is in this sense that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{a\to 0} \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r;a)=4\pi \delta(\vec r)}$$

Comment: Thank you, one more thing-why this derivative must be taken in spherical divergence but not in catesian.

Comment: @user11y3511 Actually, no.  The divergence is coordinate independent.  We merely made a convenient choice of the small volume $V_{\delta}$ to be a spherical region.  That was not required.  The result is independent of a coordinate system.